# C# Visual Studio auto increment version number by an asterisk

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, versioning

I have reference problems by using asterisk for my versionnumber in C# Visual Studio 2013.
I actually have a solution with 74 projects and each project has the following versionunmber 1.6.*

Version Number by using asterisk is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-bjtqATb0iVHvebUKoBpb9w&tduid=(395bae43449844463693656f4828bc77)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-bjtqATb0iVHvebUKoBpb9w)()).

If I (re)build the solution every project dll gets it's version number regarding to the seconds since midnight.

> For example: DLL_1 (reference to a project in my solution) =>
>   1.6.6687.1683

If I debug my compiled build the compiler does some stuff and the versionnumber of my referenced DLL_1 is increased to 1.6.6687.1793 because the DLL_1 has a new version number (I don't know why, I didn't change anything in the source code.)

If my solution is started I got an exception that he "is missing DLL_1 with versionnumber 1.6.6687.1683" because it's now 1.6.6687.1793.

What can I do to get it work?

Comment: Stop using that feature would be a solution. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4580) for a longer discussion on that issue from another angle. You should probably only change your AssemblyVersion when you actually do (breaking) changes (e.g. using  [semver](https://semver.org/) semantics). If you want to have a changing, but stable across projects version, search [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shared+assembly+version) or Google "shared assembly version". There are many usable methods out there.

Comment: @Christian.K Thanks for your answer. I use shared assembly versions and in this file I have the version number 1.6.*. But it is evaluated in each project for itself, so I have different version numbers. The problem is, I need each time, if a source code change is happended, a new version number of at least the changed project and I thought this would be de easiest way to go. Do you have a detailed hint for me? The point is, it has to be automatic so that no team meber is missing to raise the version number.